# Who I am on SMB share

Tags: windows-10, smb, credentials

There is an SMB share that I am connected to with a Windows 10 PC. Credentials have been saved long ago and forgotten.

Now I need to connect to the same share from other Windows 10 PC. In order to do so I need to look under which remote user name I am connected to this share on the first PC. How to do it?

Comment: Open powershell on the PC with the saved credentials. Type `Get-SMBConnection` It will show you the username

Comment: @Narzard: Unfortunately it shows local user names, not remote.

Answer (score 0):

Nirsoft Network Password recovery (download link: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_password_recovery.html) is a great utility for recovering saved network credential. It will show you both the local and remote credentials including SMB, Remote Desktop, IE saved passwords.